# How can I start Git Bash via Windows Terminal with environment variables set?

Tags: environment-variables, git-bash, windows-terminal

I am running Windows Terminal and Git Bash on my machine. I want to integrate Git Bash into Windows Terminal, but I want to set the environment variable `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` when running Git Bash via Windows Terminal.

I do not want to add this to my system environment variables, because I want to be able to start Git Bash outside of Windows Terminal without this environment variable.

To add Git Bash to Windows Terminal, I have created the following entry in Windows Terminal's profiles.json file:

```
        {
            "guid": "{3a20b825-3d22-41ed-b575-9006741aff64}",
            "name": "Git Bash",
            "commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
            "icon": "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
            "startingDirectory": "~",
            "hidden": false
        }
```

Here is what I have tried so far to get the environment variable to Git Bash:

- Add this environment variable as a prefix in the command: `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 "commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",`. This just results in an error message and does not start Git Bash.
- Create a batch file which first sets the environment variable using the `set` command on Windows, then runs Git Bash. This doesn't open Git Bash and instead just opens a regular cmd terminal in which the commands from the batch file are executed.
- Had a look around the [documentation for the profiles.json file](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/cascadia/SettingsSchema.md), but there is no mention of setting environment variable for terminal executables.

Is there any way that I can start my Git Bash in Windows Terminal with my custom environment variable without adding it to the system's environment variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"commandline": "cmd.exe /C \"set MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 && \"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe\"\"",
```

Or append `export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I had to use `C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe` (instead of `\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe`) in order for bash to find Unix commands. Otherwise it could not find commands like `cat` or `bash`.

Comment: Yep, I had that folder in `PATH` and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to edit `msys2.ini` directly in your MSYS2 installation if you want to keep that behaviour on other terminals.